# How can I use "white pixel icons" on Unity?

Tags: unity, icons

I'm using arc-theme for Unity and I found something its [github page](https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme) for make it same with this:

[image]

There is a description on github page for this screenshot:
"Screenshot Details: Icons: Arc | **Launcher Icons based on [White Pixel Icons](http://darkdawg.deviantart.com/art/White-Pixel-Icons-252310560)** | Wallpaper | Font: Futura Bk bt"

And I've clicked this bold text's link, a deviantart page is opened. I've downloaded white pixel icons but, it isn't like a unity icon pack. how can I use it? (I guess, it is gnome desktop in this screenshot.)

Comment: This is not Unity. Screenshot shows Gnome desktop with an extension that brings out the left-side dock that's only accessible via Activities Menu. This is also evident by square menu on the bottom of the panel as well as clock in the middle

Comment: Really? I'm sad now but anyway.. Also, thank you :)